# Django ORM filter on bool field not permitted

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

i have my django models:

```
class p_linea(models.Model):
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Linea")
    l_pubblica = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Pubblica")
    l_note = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Note interne")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Linea"
        verbose_name_plural = "Linee"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (
            str(self.l_name))


class p_catlinea(models.Model):
    p_lid = models.ForeignKey(p_linea, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Linea")
    p_cid = models.ForeignKey(p_catl, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Categoria")
    l_note = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Note interne")
    dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Upload")

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['p_cid','p_lid']),
        ]
        verbose_name = "Linea/Categoria"
        verbose_name_plural = "Linea/Categoria"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (
            str(self.p_cid))
```

now in my views.py i try to filter p_catliea baset on the fact that p_linea.l_pubblica is True, i try:

...
p_cl = p_catlinea.objects.all().select_related()

```
    for x in p_cl:
        if x.p_lid.l_pubblica:
            try:
                l_lincat[str(x.p_lid)]['cat'] = get_cat(x.p_lid_id)
            except KeyError:
                l_lincat[str(x.p_lid)] = {'cat': get_cat(x.p_lid_id),}
```

but i got error:

> 'bool' object is not callable

even if i di x.p_lid.l_pubblica == True i got the same error.

How can i filter my data based on True or Fale of related table field?

this is the full error:

> TypeError at /prodotti/
> 'bool' object is not callable
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/prodotti/
> Django Version: 3.0.5
> Exception Type: TypeError
> Exception Value:
> 'bool' object is not callable
> Exception Location: /home/kngmalza/BIGDATA/Project/tebiskin/tebiskin/prodotti/views.py in f_prodotti, line 24
> Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
> Python Version: 3.8.2
> Python Path:
> ['/home/kngmalza/BIGDATA/Project/tebiskin/tebiskin',
> '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
> '/usr/lib/python3.8',
> '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
> '/home/kngmalza/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
> '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
> Server time:    Tue, 23 Jun 2020 06:50:35 +0000

So many thanks in advance

Comment: you can follow the relations to do so. `p_catlinea.objects.filter(p_lid__l_pubblica=True)`

Comment: hi thanks but i get: 'bool' object is not callable in any case (i use postgres)

Comment: can you add the full error stacktrace please?